# How to kill all background async process run through python?

Tags: python-3.x, asynchronous, python-asyncio, psutil

I am initializing multiple asynchronous process which are running in the background to a python screen. Now, after initializing i am not able to kill all the of these background process by a keyboard interrupt or `ctrl + c`.
I have found the method of killing any individual process by using the `psutil` library. In this code we are iterating through all the running process using the function `psutil.process_iter()`. Now checking by a name and id of an individual process we are able to kill a process.

```
import psutil

for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    try:
        # Get process name & pid from process object.
        processName = proc.name()
        processID = proc.pid
        print(processName , ' ::: ', processID)
    except (psutil.NoSuchProcess, psutil.AccessDenied, psutil.ZombieProcess):
        pass

for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    if proc.name() == "powershell.exe":
        proc.kill()
```

Our main problem is that we cannot kill the asynchronous process using this piece of code and i want to kill all the processes that are initialized by python at once through any python script of using some command through terminal.

Comment: How did you start these processes?

Comment: This is not related to asyncio, these are just child processes.

Comment: I have started the processes by await asyncio.gather(multiple asynchronous method). These process are the child process but they are asynchronous in nature so i have no control on them. @Keith

Comment: From the docs: "Note The default asyncio event loop implementation on Windows does not support subprocesses."

Comment: But `asyncio.gather` takes awaitable objects, such as coroutines. Those are not OS level child processes. There is still not enough information here to give an answer.

Comment: How can i  kill the couroutine processes by using python or processes which are not os level child process

Comment: You can't. Coroutines run in the main thread, in the event loop. You can call `join` on the task.